# I have a list with checkboxes left side and I want to add only checked list items in new array

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

this is a image of list
[image: list]

from this list I want to create new array and add only checked items in new array, I don t know exactly data that will be in this list and I want dynamic solution for this problem. Sorry I could not show you the code I have no idea how the code might look.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)